# Unresolved Java compilation problem for Singleton "getInstance" function

Tags: java, singleton

I'm trying to instantiate a Singleton class in Java with VS Code.
Everytime the compiler touches the function it throws an "Unresolved Compilation Problem".

I tried creating another Singleton class and the same error applies. I thought it might be some problem of the Java Compiler so I put a few Debug.Log's before but they show up. The problem only apears with the Singleton.

In the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    GameManager gm = GameManager.getInstance();
    //gm.Start();
}
```

In the GameManager class:

```
private static GameManager instance = null;
private GameManager() {}
public static GameManager getInstance()
{
    if ( instance == null )
    {
        instance = new GameManager();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I expected to get the instance of GameManager, instead it throws an 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem" on the "public static GameManager getInstance()" line.

Comment: Unresolved compilation error means that you are trying to run code that has compilation errors.  Don't do that.  Fix the compilation errors **before** you try to run your code.

Comment: You have a different problem which cannot be reproduced by us using the code you've posted. You may need to clean  and rebuild.

Comment: Probably an issue with VSCode itself. I ran this in IntelliJ and it works

Comment: I may add that I got no errors in my code when compiling and the only problem appears to be the one in the Singleton "getInstance()"

And I'll try to clean and rebuild right now

Comment: No errors this time.  But the ".class" that you were running before did have a compilation error.  It may have been bogus ... but the behavior you saw is what some IDEs / compilers do.  They emit a .class with methods that throw `Error` if run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a *VS Code* problem.

Installed Eclipse and everything works fine now.

I don't know it it's specific to VSCode, but I'm gonna put more details in this.

This happened on *KDE Neon 5.17* , *VSCode 1.39.2* and *Java 8 OpenJDK*.